# I am facing codename: "BSONObjectTooLarge" issue while executing this MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, mongoose-schema

I executed below MongoDB query -

```
db.master_user.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      managerid: "kendrapada1@gmail.com",
      passcode: "KENDRAPADA0123",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tch_teacher_baseline_endline",
      localField: "userid",
      foreignField: "userid",
      as: "baselnEndlnDetails",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ppt_trans",
      localField: "userid",
      foreignField: "userid",
      as: "pptDetails",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tch_teacher_training",
      localField: "userid",
      foreignField: "userid",
      as: "trainingDetails",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "trans_nsdc",
      localField: "userid",
      foreignField: "userid",
      as: "nsdcDetails",
    },
  },
  { $sort: { username: 1 } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      userid: 1,
      username: 1,
      gender: 1,
      contactnumber: 1,
      createdon: 1,
      status: 1,
      graduated: 1,
      baselnEndlnDetails: 1,
      pptDetails: 1,
      trainingDetails: 1,
      nsdcDetails: 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

Earlier it was working fine, I had executed this query many times but yesterday I am getting this error.

I am getting error -

```
{
    "message" : "Executor error during getMore :: caused by :: BSONObj size: 24445027 (0x1750063) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: graduated: 'no'",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 10334,
    "codeName" : "BSONObjectTooLarge"
}
```

I was expecting a JSON output earlier it was working fine but now its not working. Help me with this query or do I need to write it any another way kindly help me.

Comment: The error messages is quite clear I would say. Having an aggregation pipeline with four `$lookup` stages looks like a rather poor database design. NoSQL databases like MongoDB are not relational databases, they are not optimized for joins (some NoSQL databases do not even support joins at all).

Comment: Have a look at [Join Conditions and Subqueries on a Joined Collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection). In the inner pipeline you can remove fields which are not required in your result.

Comment: Do you store passcode as clear text? Would be serious security flaw!

Comment: Thank you for your response. The field name is passcode but it is not a passcode as name suggests it is a key to identify group of users. Can you help me with below points  
1. how to do a proper database design?
2. If we want data from multiple tables what is the solution? (Any alternate solution of my query).

Comment: Without sample input data and desired result it is difficult to give any suggestions.